# Easylist inside ntheorem

Tags: lists, itemize, ntheorem, easylist

I want to use easylist inside a ntheorem environment. But it doesn't indent nested lists.

Cropped PDF:
[image: Cropped PDF]
Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}

% ntheorem config
\theoremstyle{break}
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries\large}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremseparator{\medskip}
\theorempostskip{\topsep\medskip}
\newtheorem{exercise}{Excercise}


\begin{document}

Outside theorem

\begin{easylist}[itemize]
& Main item~:
&& Sub item.
&&& Another sub item.
\end{easylist}


\begin{exercise}

Inside theorem

\begin{easylist}[itemize]
& Main item~:
&& Sub item.
&&& Another sub item.
\end{easylist}

\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I don't think it can be made to work, because an `easylist` cannot be nested in other list structures, which a theorem internally is.

Comment: I just tried it with amsthm instead of ntheorem and it worked. Is amsthm implemented differently? http://pastebin.com/fnFeqwZN

Comment: Yes, quite differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A work around is to include the `easylist` in a `minipage` inside the theorem/exercise:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}

% ntheorem config
\theoremstyle{break}
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries\large}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremseparator{\medskip}
\theorempostskip{\topsep\medskip}
\newtheorem{exercise}{Excercise}


\begin{document}

Outside theorem

\begin{easylist}[itemize]
& Main item~:
&& Sub item.
&&& Another sub item.
\end{easylist}


\begin{exercise}

Inside theorem

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{1.0\linewidth}
  \begin{easylist}[itemize]
    & Main item~:
    && Sub item.
    &&& Another sub item.
  \end{easylist}
\end{minipage}
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```